# Problem with building jar file with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar

I need to export a jar file which could be execute in server. I try many of answers in this site and other site, but I guess my main problem is :

```
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for mybot:energyBot:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/Users/narges/.m2/repository/bot/mBot/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/energyBot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
```

Here is part of my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>mybot</groupId>
            <artifactId>myBot</artifactId>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>$/Users/narges/eclipse-workspace/Bot/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your pom.xml, plugin works fine with boot applications as well.

```
   <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>/your/path</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: FYI: Code-only answers are highly discouraged here. Please consider adding more details about how this answers OP's question in order to prevent your post from getting downvotes and being flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wrote `myBot`/`energyBot` yourself? You added it as a Maven plugin, but it seems like it is not a Maven plugin, but maybe just a plain jar.

If you want to put all dependencies into your jar, you need the assembly plugin or the shade plugin.